# index.html imports for angular2 rc.0.1

Tags: angular

i recently upgraded my ng2 app from beta2.0.12 to rc.0.1. Previously i had following imports in my index.html :

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

What are the corresponding imports for rc.0.1. Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: [The quick start guide gives a good example of how to use rc1](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question firstly me too confuse about imports in the RC.0 but than i found my answer,

actually in the RC.0 of angular2 all the imports has been mentioned in the `system.config.js` file,
look at this file carefully than you will see all the imports here

```
(function (global) {

  var map = {
    ...
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'   // here angular2 bind all the imports of @angular from the node_modules folder itself
                                            instead of importing in the index.html
    ...
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',      //Here all the imports bind by name like from core/common and all...
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  // '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

})(this);
```

so in the RC.0 no need to import `angular.dev/router/http` file of angular in the index.html file.all these
imports has been imported via system.config.js file.